# How Can I generate PINs and Print Multiple Unique Recharge PIN in Django

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Ticketing project where I want the admin to be to generate multiple unique numeric PINs that customers can purchase and can be validated on the app for event registration. I have researched and realised that this could also be done using bulk create but don't know how.
Here is my Ticket Model

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    name =models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want a situation where admin would be able to generate multiple PINs for a particular ticket with a click but don't know how to go about it so someone should please help with the best way of doing it.

Comment: How many PINs the admin should be able to generate each time? Can two tickets have the same PIN?

Comment: You can use postgres `ArrayField` or separate `Pin` model for that with FK to `Ticket`.

Comment: The admin should be able to generate 20 PINs at once. Each ticket should have unique PINs

Comment: @SUTerliakov I want to see the code that does that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create another model `TicketPIN` which has a `ForeignKey` relation to `Ticket` model:

```
from random import randint

from django.db import models

def generate_pin():
    return ''.join(str(randint(0, 9)) for _ in range(6))

class TicketPIN(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=6, default=generate_pin, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["ticket", "value"]

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ticket} | {self.value}"
```

You won't need the pin field inside the `Ticket` model.
Next, you should create a view that only superuser can access:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

from .models import Ticket, TicketPIN

def generate_pins_for_ticket(request, ticket_id):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        ticket = Ticket.objects.get(id=ticket_id)
        for _ in range(20):
            TicketPIN.objects.create(ticket=ticket)
        return JsonResponse({"message": f"Created 20 PINs successfully for {ticket} ticket."})
    return JsonResponse({"error": "Not Authorized"})
```

And in `urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import generate_pins_for_ticket 

urlpatterns = [
        path("generate-pins/<int:ticket_id>", generate_pins_for_ticket),
]
```

Let's say the admin created a ticket that has `id=1`, when the admin is logged out, any user that visits `/generate-pins/1` will see the response `{"error": "Not Authorized"}`. Only if the admin is logged in and he visits `/generate-pins/1` will generate 20 PINs. you can modify the view to accept any number to generate and create a form so it's admin-friendly.

Comment: Hope I Can return and render an HTML template with the generated PIN after PIN generation.

Answer (score 1):

This is for comments but since my reputation doesn't reach 50 let me added this:

If I understand you, you want when user submitted the **Ticket** model that **Ticket** will generated the a random number automatically in the admin.

This can be done using Python module called [Random](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) or using Django modules called [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/)

**Django Signals**

Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place. They’re especially useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.

**Python module Random**

This module implements pseudo-random number generators for various distributions.

For integers, there is uniform selection from a range. For sequences, there is uniform selection of a random element, a function to generate a random permutation of a list in-place, and a function for random sampling without replacement.